# Is there any way to use appium with xcode 8, iOS 10, real device

Tags: iphone, swift3, automation, appium

Is there any way to use appium 1.6 with xcode 8, iOS 10, real device.

Currently I am using appium 1.4 and while running it with xcode 8(swift 3 coding) , iOS 10 real device I am getting some errors and I have searched on some sites where its given that there is not any successful compatibility yet of xcode 8 with appium.

Is that true? If anyone can explain exact remark about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the appium scripts on ios 10 devices xcode 8 is mandatory.If you have xcode 8 you can run the scripts on ios 10 simulators and also real devices.

For this you need to install appium 1.6 and this is not GUI app like appium 1.5.3. You have to launch appium 1.6.0 from terminal only.